# e.stopPropagation() not working for nested element's onClick event inside <th> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a dynamic table that allows sorting. (Yeah, I know there's libraries for this, but I figured why not try making it myself).

So essentially I'm rendering some table-headers `<th>`, and the active header has an icon `<span>`.

The `header` has an `onClick` handler that disables the field.

The `icon` has an `onClick` handler that will eventually sort the data by that field.

The icon is nested inside the header like so:

```
if (displayExtendedFields && data.length > 0) {
  return (
    <tr>
      {Object.keys(data[0])
        .filter(item => !inactiveFields.includes(item))
        .map(field => (
          <th
            className="table-header"
            onClick={() => this.disableField(field)}
          >
            {field}
            <span
              className="sort-icon"
              onClick={e => this.sortByField(e, field)}
            >
              {activeField.name === field && <KeyboardArrowUp />}
            </span>
          </th>
        ))}
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Clicking the icon will execute this event-handler:

```
  sortByField = (e, field) => {
    e.stopPropgation();
    const { activeField } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      activeField: { ...activeField, name: field }
    });
  };
```

The logic runs, but it does not stop the events from bubbling upwards, even though I do have `e.stopPropagation()`. The header's click-event still runs and disables the field, which is odd.

See sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sortable-table-jzgn2

Comment: typo: `e.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: @JosephD. lol thanks.